# Android physics engine (camera on top)

Tags: android, 2d, physics, physics-engine

I'm developing a game for Android, but I need an physics engine that allows me detect and response an collision (I developed a simple game with Nape Physis), but I need that this physics engine allow that all objects allows be on the ground, and the "camera" will be on the top of the game objects and not vertically. So, the physics engine just need a detection of collision and response that, don't need anything like gravity.

Someone have a tip for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jBox2d works quite well and if you're also interested in a framework that draws graphics, use it in combination with AndEngine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it. Just one more thing, can you provide me an example (can be a link with it) that shows how can create the space on horizontally (like I'm asking for)?

Comment: I don't know for sure what you mean but both frameworks come with a complete set of examples. You may change them properly in order to get your type of game. Good luck.